# Is it possible to workaround the Redshift geoclue bug?

Tags: redshift

People have asked about this bug before, but it hasn't really been answered yet.

`Redshift` used to work fine for me, but now it doesn't any more. I don't know how that happened. There seems to be some problem with the `geoclue` service or something.

Can't we

1. Manually toggle `Redshift` on and off, without needing any location?
2. Set the location manually?

I don't really care about any of the automation, I just want a working screen dimmer. There is an alternative called "Iris" but it's a paid app.

Here is what happens

```
 arun@arun-GP70-2OD:~$ redshift
 Trying location provider `geoclue'...
 Started Geoclue provider `Geoclue Master'.
 Using provider `geoclue'.

 ** (process:4125): WARNING **: Could not get location, 3 retries left.


 ** (process:4125): WARNING **: Could not get location, 2 retries left.


 ** (process:4125): WARNING **: Could not get location, 1 retries left.


 ** (process:4125): WARNING **: Provider does not have a valid location available.
 Unable to get location from provider.
```

The same thing happens when I use `gtk-redshift` and `redshift-gtk`.

Comment: You can give redshift a location, for example, the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/redshift) has one for Copenhagen, Denmark: `redshift -l 55.7:12.6`.

Comment: @mikewhatever Yes, it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/blob/master/redshift.conf.sample) for the configuration file, you can specify manually location, color temperature, etc…

For example, if you were in Copenhagen, you could run `redshift-gtk -l 55.7:12.6`. That will also launch the panel indicator.

Comment: Yes, I was able to run it with this `redshift -l 12.1:79.3 -t 5700:2000 -g 0.8 -m vidmode -v` and it works great. But does this mean that I can no longer see the GUI, like the panel icon?

Comment: No, if you modify the configuration file, you can have redshift-gtk start at login still, and the options will be preserved across logins/reboots, so you don't have to run redshift manually every time.

Comment: I guess you merely need to replace `redshift` with `redshift-gtk` in the command above.

Comment: @Sadi I'm sleepy, I'll get back to you and Dobey tomorrow. This is very interesting. I've gotta make this work.

Comment: No problem. I actually use the command `killall redshift && redshift-gtk [MyOptions...]` in a shell script, and then enter its full path in the `~/.config/autostart/redshift-gtk.desktop` file's `Exec=` line.

Comment: @Sadi This worked great, I added that to a shell script, which can be added to startup applications or assigned to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I did this but it doesn't seem to pay attention to the time, thinks it's daytime at night.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a geoclue-2.0 available, which solves the issue for me (Ubuntu Mate 16.04, redshift-gtk) and for [this guy](http://compizomania.blogspot.com/2016/12/redshift-linux-mint.html) (Linux Mint).

I removed redshift first (just a security step) by

```
apt-get purge redshift
```

And then did how instructed in russian:

```
sudo apt-get install redshift-gtk geoclue-2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Update */etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf* [config file](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/318#issuecomment-796530534)!

> whitelist=org.freedesktop.DBus;_geoclue-demo-agent;gnome-shell;io.elementary.desktop.agent-geoclue2
>
> [org.freedesktop.DBus]
> allowed=true
> system=true
> users=